# Mysql get how old (in N days) min(Date) is?

Tags: mysql

I'm grouping posts by `Verb` and getting the date from the oldest row with min(Date). I want to know how many days ago this date exists.

This is my currenty query:

```
SELECT min(Date) AS firstPost FROM `Posts` GROUP BY `verb`
```

How can I get how old (in n days) min(Date) is?

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT min(Date) AS firstPost,
         DATEDIFF(NOW(), min(Date)) `age_in_days`
    FROM `Posts`
GROUP BY `verb`
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
SELECT min(Date) AS firstPost 
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), min(Date)) AS dueDate
FROM `Posts` 
GROUP BY `verb`
```

`DATEDIFF()` returns the number of days between the start date and the end date.